# How can I stop a hash key from overwriting duplicates in ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap, overwrite

I'm making a madlib; in the paragraph it finds words that look like this: `[noun]`, `[verb]` or `[adjective]`. It does that fine but when I prompt the user for the desired word they want for that position it keeps overwriting the key with the already existing key (I'm guessing because they have the same name). But I don't know how to stop it from overwriting it; I've tried merging but I can't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
class MadLib
  def initialize(input)
    p @input_string = read_file(input)
    p @parsed_inputs = parse(@input_string)
    p @hashed_input_values = {}
  end

  def take_input
    @parsed_inputs.each do |key|
      parse_key = key.match(/:/)

      if parse_key
        print "Enter #{parse_key.post_match} :"
        value = STDIN.gets.chomp
        @hashed_input_values["[#{key}]"] = value
        @hashed_input_values["[#{parse_key.pre_match}]"] = value
        @parsed_inputs.delete(parse_key.pre_match)
      else
        print "Enter #{key} :"
        @hashed_input_values["[#{key}]"] = STDIN.gets.chomp
      end
    end

    @hashed_input_values
  end

  def print_output
    @input_string.gsub(/\[(\w*:*\w)]/i, @hashed_input_values)
  end

  def parse(input)
    # f = File.open(input)
    input.scan(/\[(\w*:*\w)]/i).flatten
  end

  def read_file(file_name)
    file = File.read(file_name)
  end

  private :parse
end

madlib = MadLib.new(ARGV[0])

# test = "Story1.txt"
# madlib = MadLib.new(test)
madlib.take_input
puts "#{madlib.print_output}"
```

And here is the text file I've been using:

```
Everyone was so [adjective] to [verb] all of the [adjective] animals. The star of the show was a [adjective] [noun] named Bobo.
```

Comment: You need to use a different key for each occurrence of a given [part of speech]. Initialize a counter at zero, increment it each time you see a [part of speech] in the text, and use it in the hash key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash's behavior of replacing the value for a given key with a new value is the intended behavior of a hash.  We expect and need hashes to behave that way.

As previously said by others, you need to give each key a unique name. You could name the adjectives `adjective1`, `adjective2`, etc.  If you want to hide the numbers from the user, you could easily remove them in the string that you display.  It might not be so bad to even leave them in.

It might seem that implementing each part of speech as an array so that you'd have adjectives[0], etc., is a better design, but for the MadLibs use case, I don't think so.  The adjectives don't really have anything more in common with each other than they do with instances of other parts of speech.

Comment: Would it be a good idea then to make 3 hashmaps to store only a certain type, like one for nouns, one for verbs and one for adjective? So then I could keep count of how many nouns there are.

Comment: I don't think so.  Why do you need to keep count?  If the keys were something totally unrelated to part of speech (e.g. :bluebird, :cardinal, :sparrow) wouldn't it work the same?  All you need the part of speech for is to prompt the user, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write only first value for given key - use ||=

```
hash = {}
hash[:a] ||= 1 # => { a: 1 }
hash[:a] ||= 2 # => { a: 1 }
```

Comment: I't more like with this would I be able to have to spots in the hashmap that are called "noun" but they have different values?

Comment: You cant have multiple keys in hash with the same name. But you can store multiple values for given key, and use any of them later
`hash = {}
(1, 2, 3).each do |i|
  hash[:a] ||= []
  hash[:a] << i
end
# { a: [1, 2, 3] }`
Maybe in will help.

Comment: Алексей Кузнецов I think you misunderstood the question.  He needs to have all the values, not just the first one.